# Color not changing for Unicode check mark 2714 on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, unicode

In the code below the color of Unicode check mark 2713 changes to green as expected in various environments, but the color of Unicode check mark 2714 doesn't change to green in Safari or Chrome for iOS.

Is some special handling needed here, or is this just a bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    p {
        color:green;
        font-size: 400%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Unicode 2713: &#x2713</p>
<p>Unicode 2714: &#x2714</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat, U+2714 is an emoji, while U+2713 is not.  Since the iPhone renders emojis as images, one can't change the color.